# How to Clear Facebook Integration "Use object id instant" warning?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, frameworks

Using my application facebook integration  **'id' is deprecated: use objectID instead** Waring has shown .how to clear the warning my coding is below screenhot[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change id to objectID

```
self.profilePicture.profileID = user.objectID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this Code:

```
[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *FBuser, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
      // Handle error
    }

    else {
      NSString *userId = [FBuser id];

    }
  }];
```